# NestJS GraphQL Api Package Installation Not Working

Tags: node.js, graphql, nest

I cloned a repository that is built using NestJS and GraphQL. And I tried to install the package inside the package.json using "npm i" command. And I am getting the error below. What should I do for the project to start running after installing all the packages?

I have tried upgrading my node and npm versions.
I have tried upgrading node-gyp

```
npm WARN deprecated apollo-datasource@3.3.2: The `apollo-datasource` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ 
for more details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-errors@3.3.1: The `apollo-server-errors` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/server` 
package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ 
for more details.
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-server-env@4.2.1: The `apollo-server-env` package is part of Apollo Server v2 and v3, which are now deprecated (end-of-life October 22nd 2023). This package's functionality is now found in the `@apollo/utils.fetcher` package. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/previous-versions/ for more details.
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\Bonny\\Documents\\OromoRecipe-main\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\schematics',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\@nestjs\schematics'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\Bonny\\Documents\\OromoRecipe-main\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\schematics'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt      
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node" (not found)      
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.1.0/bcrypt_lib-v5.1.0-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http download proxy agent configured using: "127.0.0.1:13728"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install request to https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.1.0/bcrypt_lib-v5.1.0-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 13728
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@5.1.0 and node@18.14.2 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error request to https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v5.1.0/bcrypt_lib-v5.1.0-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 13728
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or 
newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studionpm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload. 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:     
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:369:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:390:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:427:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)  
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bonny\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Bonny\\Documents\\OromoRecipe-main\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Bonny\\Documents\\OromoRecipe-main\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)   
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bonny\\Documents\\OromoRecipe-main\\node_modules\\@mapbox\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Bonny\Documents\OromoRecipe-main\node_modules\bcrypt
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bonny\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-07T10_46_00_058Z-debug-0.log
```